# Publish a project release (binary/source packages) on Github?

Tags: github, release

Does `Github` offer the option to create release-page for a project? I've noticed it let you create different tag for the source, but couldn't find the UI/web where I can add release notes, built package(s) and all that.

Comment: How should we know? Ask the github folks.

Comment: The release feature has just been added to GitHub! See [my edited answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14916525/6309).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Update 2d July 2013](https://github.com/blog/1547-release-your-software), you now can **define a release**.

> **Releases**, a workflow for shipping software to end users.
>   Releases are first-class objects with changelogs and binary assets that present a full project history beyond Git artifacts. They're accessible from a repository's homepage:

[image: homepage]

- Releases are accompanied by release notes and links to download the software or source code.
- Following the conventions of many Git projects, releases are tied to Git tags. You can use an existing tag, or let releases create the tag when it's published.
- **You can also attach binary assets (such as compiled executables, minified scripts, documentation) to a release**. Once published, the release details and assets are available to anyone that can view the repository.

[image: release]

That is what replaces the [old binary upload service](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6978954/6309), which was [removed in December 2012](https://github.com/blog/1302-goodbye-uploads)!

---

Initial answer (February 2012)

Not that I know of: this is very dependent of each project language and release management process.

One way would be to use the `README.md` to publish those information, or to link to the release notes as a separate document.
The nice detail about a link is that it can, since a few weeks, be a *relative* one (see blog post "[Relative links in markup files](https://github.com/blog/1395-relative-links-in-markup-files)").

Comment: I just to tried to upload an update site to a GitHub release like this answer suggests, but I could not find a way to replicate the required directory structure. When I try to upload the `features` or the `plugins` folder I get an error saying the file is larger than 1 Gb.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa whar "directory structure"? https://github.com/blog/1547-release-your-software only mention the possibility to upload a zip file. You can zip any directory structure you want.

Comment: Ok I see now what you propose. I was expecting a real web directory structure that could be used directly as a location in the Eclipse "Install software" dialogue.

Comment: What I referenced in the first question, `features` and  `plugins`, basically what you get after compiling an Update Site project.