# Support for auto generated "Release notes" in GitLab

Tags: continuous-integration, project-management, jira, gitlab

We are planning on migrating from Jira+Gerrit to GitLab. One important feature that we are using in Jira is the auto generation of [release notes](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Creating+Release+Notes).

Question: Is there any similar functionality in GitLab?

Comment: 7 years later( 2020, this is supported by a gitlab-ci workflow now, on GitLab: see [my edited answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23322600/6309)

Answer (score 2):

2020: this is possible with GitLab, see:

> ### [How GitLab is automating release generation in `.gitlab-ci.yml`](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2020/05/07/how-gitlab-automates-releases/), from [Jackie Meshell](https://gitlab.com/jreporter)

> The `release-cli` tool is written in Go and can be called directly to create a Release via the API, given the right job token and parameters are provided.
> The more likely way users will interact with this tool will be in the YAML file as a job:

```
release_upload:
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:v0.1.0
  script:
    - gitlab-releaser create --name="My Release" --description="My Release description"
```

---

Note that GitHub also support a [similar feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69108043/6309) in Oct. 2021, as annouced in [GitHub Universe 2021](https://github.blog/2021-10-27-everything-new-from-universe-2021/#%E2%9C%A8-improved-daily-flow).

---

2014: Not in GitHub directly.

If your commit messages follow some policy, you could consider generating a release note from said commits.

See for instance:

- "[generating release notes from Git commits](https://coderwall.com/p/gkw6tg)"
- "[Generate HISTORY.md from @github Milestones and Tags](https://gist.github.com/itayw/10249629)" ([mentioned by BestGit](https://twitter.com/BestGit/status/453939710038392832))

Comment: Sry I meant GitLab and not GitHub. So the 2:nd option is not an option! :)

Comment: @UT_lol sure, but you get the general idea: as long as you can rxtract (from git notes or git commit messages or...) relevant information for release notes, you can generate them that way.a

Answer (score 2):

Well, update to gitlab 8.2.0
https://about.gitlab.com/2015/11/22/gitlab-8-2-released/

It says you have the ability to add release notes (markdown text and attachments) to git tags (aka Releases).

Now just create a tag per release, and then you'll see the markdown.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested, I have developed a Python lib to generate release notes or changelog automatically, listing merge requests since the last release of a GitLab repository. The source code is here with instructions on how to use it: https://github.com/vuillaut/gitlab_release_notes

You may use the online app here for a more convenient approach: https://purl.org/gitlab_release_notes/app