# What exactly is a Release in GitHub?

Tags: git, github, release, github-api

- What is it exactly?
- For what is it used?
- How widespread is the usage?
- How is it usually used?

Comment: Note: since Apr. 2021, a GitHub Release can be commented/discussed. See my [edited answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33587799/6309).

Answer (score 39):

[From Official GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/about-releases/):

**Releases** are **GitHub's** way of packaging and providing software to your users. You can think of it as a replacement to using downloads to provide software.

With **Releases**, you can provide links to binary files, as well as release notes describing your changes.

At their core, **Releases** are based on [Git tags](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging). Tags mark a specific point in the history of your project, so they're a great way to indicate a Release. **Releases** are ordered by a tag's date in the following way:

- If it's an [annotated tag](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging#_annotated_tags), the tag object's date is used.
- If it's a [lightweight tag](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging#_lightweight_tags), then the commit object's date is used.

For more information about viewing your existing tags, see [Working With Tags](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-tags/).

Answer (score 36):

> I would like to backup this official explanation from people who are already using that to see how it works.

## Definition

As mentioned in "[About Releases](https://help.github.com/articles/about-releases/)"

> Releases are GitHub's way of packaging and providing software to your users. You can think of it as a replacement to using downloads to provide software.

**A release is a container of one or more assets, associated to a git annotated tag** (since [`git push --follow-tags` only pushes annotated tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26438076/6309))

[It replaces since July 2013 an old "GitHub Download" system](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14034459/6309) which was [beginning to get abused](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6978988/6309) (people stored anything and everything in it), and removed in Dec. 2012.
By forcing an indirection (tag => release => asset), GitHub made that feature more manageable.

[dirkjot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/230446/dirkjot) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33551505/what-exactly-is-a-release-in-github/33587799?noredirect=1#comment110399522_33587799):

> Two great points that are easily overlooked:
>
> 1. A release is initially "empty" because it is associated with a tag, not generated from that tag
> 2. Assets are uploaded so not necessarily related to the source code.
>
> Footnote: An empty release will automatically contain a tgz and zip version of the source at the tagged commit

---

## Usage

A GitHub release is used:

- to avoid storing large *generated* binaries built from project in a *source* control system like git.
- by users of a repo to download the "end result", ie the "delivery" already built for them from a git repo content, even if they don't have git.

---

## Example

An example of a project using releases would be [git for windows releases](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases).
In the case of [git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/), that comes in handy considering that you might want to install git in the first place, and you might not have the right tool-set to compile its sources.

---

## API consideration

As the [GitHub V3 Release API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#releases) illustrates, a release is *not* a tag.
When you [create a release](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/releases#create-a-release), you would need the name of a tag, but that would create an *empty* release (associated to that tag)

From a release, you can [upload one or more assets to it](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/releases#upload-a-release-asset).

The asset data is expected in its raw binary form.

```
POST https://<upload_url>/repos/:owner/:repo/releases/:id/assets?name=foo.zip
```

---

Note: GitLab also supports "release" [since GitLab 8.2 (Nov. 2015)](https://about.gitlab.com/2015/11/22/gitlab-8-2-released/).

---

## Discussion

Since Apr. 2021, you now have:

> ### [Releases support comments and reactions with Discussion linking](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-04-06-releases-support-comments-and-reactions-with-discussion-linking/)
>
> You can now link discussions to new releases!
>
> When drafting a new release, check the Create a discussion for this release box, choose a category, and publish.
> Your community will be able to react and comment on the release notes, giving projects more opportunities to celebrate and receive feedback.
> Release discussions are also available natively on GitHub Mobile.
>
> [image: enable discussion creation on a release -- https://i1.wp.com/user-images.githubusercontent.com/1923260/113341794-76e64a00-92e2-11eb-9d35-3f843d0a313c.png?w=1208&ssl=1]
>
> For more information, see [GitHub Discussions](https://docs.github.com/en/discussions), [GitHub Releases](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/about-releases) and [GitHub Mobile](https://docs.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/github-for-mobile) documentation.

---

Note that in Q3 2021, you could have a [native changelog generator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69108043/6309).

---

And from June 2022, you can set/change/modify a release notes for a *previous* release (or past release):

> ### You can now manually select a previous release when generating release notes
>
> It is now possible to manually select the previous release prior to generating release notes in the GitHub Releases UI.
>
> For more information on Generating Release Notes, see the [Automatically Generated Release Notes documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/releasing-projects-on-github/automatically-generated-release-notes).
> For more information on GitHub Releases, see the [GitHub Releases documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/about-releases).

Comment: Can you edit the design of your answer? The content is good but it should get an rework for an quality answer. I made that question mainly for other people to find it, so it deserve an answer which is easy readable.

Comment: @BerndErnst Sure. I have rewritten the answer accordingly.

Comment: Two great points that are easily overlooked:  1/ A release is initially "empty" because it is  associated with a tag not generated from that tag  2/ Assets are uploaded so not necessarily related to the source code.
Footnote:  An empty release will automatically contain a tgz and zip version of the source at the tagged commit.

Comment: @dirkjot Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @Noum Thank you for the updated URLs. Much appreciated.