# What is the visibility when you "publish" a release of a private repository on GitHub?

Tags: github

I am working with a project on a private GitHub repository. I'm looking to bundle up source code (based on a given tag) plus some binary objects as a release.

My question is what does it truly mean to "publish" a release? The [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/managing-releases-in-a-repository) only tell me that publishing a release will "publicize" it:

> If you're ready to publicize your release, click Publish release.

When the "publish" button is clicked, does a notification get sent out? Who gets notified, and/or who can see the actual release? Since this is a private repository I don't want notification or visibility to the GitHub community as a whole.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What exactly is a Release in GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33551505/what-exactly-is-a-release-in-github)

Comment: @fatalcoder524 nope, it doesn't. That only talks about what a release itself is, and doesn't speak to my real questions of 1) the visibility of the release itself, and 2) who, if anyone, gets notified when the release is published.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the notifications are sent to all the people who are watching your repo. Also if you are in your organization repo, it will be notified to all the users of your organization.

Comment: What about visibility to others? "Publish Release" sounds like the release will be public. That's not acceptable for a private project.

Answer (score 1):

Publishing means "make it visible" to the people who have access.  Publishing a release to a private repository makes it visible to the people that have been given access to the private repository.